# Could not request GET API deployed to local Tomcat server using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, tomcat

Using Spring and Maven, I built and deployed a WAR project to local Tomcat server, and when I access the API using the browser, it works :

```
http://localhost:8015/keystroke-backend/user
```

I  got :

```
[{"id":1,"username":"bilal","password":"pass"}]
```

But when I access it using JQuery using AJAX, nothing happenned:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Event to check the input data
$("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8015/keystroke-backend/user"
    }).then(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    });
});
});
```

Nothing happens.

And this is the GET API :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class KeystrokeController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> doGetUsers() {

    List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
    try {
        // Get the list of users from the database
        usersList = UsersDB.getDB().getUsers();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(usersList, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(usersList, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
}
}
```

I see this error from the console :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/testing-client/test/server-status/1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Note that when I use the same code to access something else like the following:

```
      url: "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"
```

It works. Any idea ?

Comment: post your controller method

Comment: @Lucky , I just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the content type in the Ajax request solves the issue.

```
$("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8015/keystroke-backend/user",
        contentType:"application/json"
    }).then(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your input type as button not submit, and also change here. In never use button type submit for ajax.

```
$("#login-form").click(function(e) {
```

Comment: It is the same, maybe the issue is not related to JQuery but with using local Tomcat server, because when I use the same code to request public API , it works.

Comment: It's not tomcat problem as `you can access the API using the browser, and it works`